# Python 3 logging to site using name and password

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, login-script

There is a site and many pictures are open only for users who signed in

How to log to this site without modules GET (doesn't work with Python3 in Windows), mechanize (doesn't work with python 3) and other modules which don't work with python3.4

here is a part of code from the page which works for entering (I translated several words in it to English):

```
#<form id="form1" action="" method="post" class="registration">
                            <input name="f_login" type="hidden" id="f_login" value="1">
                                    <fieldset style="width: 195; height: 92">
                                        <dl>
                                          <dt><label for="login">Login</label></dt>
                                          <dd><input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="input"/></dd>
                                        </dl>
                                        <dl>
                                          <dt><label for="pass">Password</label></dt>
                                          <dd><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="input"/></dd>
                                        </dl>
                                You have not entered the system
                                        <br><a href="/index.php?action=register">Registration</a>
                                        <button type="submit" class="enter">Enter</button>                      
                                        <br><a href="/index.php?action=retrieve">remind password</a>
                                    </fieldset>
                                  </form>
```

Comment: Try [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org).

Comment: Thank you. I was using requests and it didn't work. Then I saw in browser that it was sending 3 values instead of 2 (login, password AND f_login). After adding the 3rd value - everything worked fine. ))))

Answer (score 0):

I've found the decision. ))) It has 2 parts:

1. We go to the site, give our name, password and other things which needed, and save cookies which site gives us:

   payload = {
           'f_login': '1',    ### not nessessary, thats just the other thing which MY site requested
           'login': 'your_site_login',
           'pass': 'your_site_password'
       }

   ```
   with requests.Session() as v:
           p = v.post('http://YOUR_SITE/index.php', data=payload) ## saying our credentials to the site
           pk=v.cookies  ## saving cookies as "pk"
   ```

2) after this we just use cookies "pk" every time when we address our site:

```
requests.get('http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?action=photos=all', cookies=pk)
```

or

```
requests.post('http://YOUR_SITE/ajaxdata.php?mod=edit_note&userid', cookies=pk)
```

Works perfectly in my case. )))